# Убрать класс jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Такой вопрос нужно при повторном клике убрать класс active с активной кнопки.

http://jsfiddle.net/8g8tB/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С минимальными изменениями.

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/8g8tB/3/

```
$(function() {
  $("#menu ul li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $t=$(this).not('.active');
    $("#menu ul li a").removeClass('active');    
    $t.addClass('active');
  })
});
```

в общем в $t окажется только тогда элемент, когда у него не было класса active.

второй вариант - http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/8g8tB/4/ , мне кажется он хуже, а вообще сейчас подобные вещи модно на css делать :) (правда включение-выключение что-то я не могу придумать как )

Comment: Благодарю, то что нужно.

Comment: @eicto, чтобы реализовать включение и выключение можно использовать checkbox'ы. :)

Answer (score 2):

**[Пример без скриптов](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/8g8tB/5/)**

1) атрибут **id** должен быть уникальным на странице.
2) не используйте тэг **a** только для того, что повесить обработчик события **onclick**;
 для этого подойдет любой элемент.
3) старайтесь не повторяться в стилях;
вам будет проще следить за этим, если вы будете писать css-свойства в алфавитном порядке.

**html**

```
<div id="menu" class="menu">
    <ul id="spisok">
        <li>
            <input id="button-1" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
            <label class="menubutton" for="button-1">кнопка 1</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input id="button-2" type="checkbox" />
            <label class="menubutton" for="button-2">кнопка 2</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**css** (удалил ненужные значения стилей, совпадающие со стандартными, и убрал повторы)

```
.menu {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.menu ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.menubutton {
    background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.35);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #393e52;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    padding: 16px 21px;
}
input[id^="button-"] {
    display: none;
}
input[id^="button-"]:checked + .menubutton {
    background-color: #00E509;
    padding-left: 18px;
}
```

Comment: @VenZell тут переключения не происходит :) я думаю совсем без скриптов не  обойтись, зато можно обойтись без уникальных id http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/8g8tB/6/

Comment: @eicto, прочитав вопрос, я увидел, что нужно при повторном нажатии "гасить" кнопку при повторном нажатии. Поэтому чекбокс. Сейчас увидел комментарий, где надо и "гасить", кнопку и "переключать". Так что радиобаттон тоже не подходит... Надо подумать.

Comment: ну там есть конечно извратный вариант, [в  таком духе](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/bHNPN/) ... но я думаю перебор.

Comment: А последняя-то все равно не убирается ;)

Comment: да это как пример изврата, вот в подобную сторону лишний раз думать не хочется.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/8g8tB/2/

Comment: такой вариант не подходит, т.к. в моем примере при нажатии на другую кнопку класс active с предыдущей пропадает, а в данном примере остается. Нужно, чтобы при перекликивании с одной кнопки на другую, у предыдущей активный класс пропадал, а при повторном нажатии на активную кнопку и у нее класс пропадал.

Comment: @RageXL, а почему сразу не описали проблему детальнее? здесь не все телепаты

Comment: Мое упущение, признаю)